# vim : plugin for a file type

Tags: plugins, vim

If I have a plugin, how I can activate this only in python files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a ftplugin. (`:h ftplugin`). See [Detect filetype from within VIM plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151692/detect-filetype-from-within-vim-plugin/2153946#2153946)